# Is it possible to batch on item metadata?

Tags: msbuild

Given the following MSBuild project file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="DoA" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <A Include="1.txt">
      <Define>B=2;C=3</Define>
    </A>
    <A Include="2.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="DoA" Inputs="@(A)" Outputs="out\%(A.Filename).csv">
    <Message Text="perl myscript.pl @(A) ???" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

What do I need to substitute for the `???` to have the text output be:

```
perl myscript.pl 1.txt --define B=2 --define C=3
perl myscript.pl 2.txt
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%(A.Define)` but you'd have to change your Define property to:

```
<Define>--define B=2 --define C=3</Define>
```

I don't believe it's possible to treat item metadata as an item itself, though it does seem useful in this case.

Comment: That's what I figured...oh, well.